# Multithreading in SWT?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm working on a SWT application for creating a automatic testing tool. I need to implement multithreading and I've heard Eclipse jobs Api can help me with it. I couldn't find it with my eclipse bundle. Can anyone point me to the location where I could download it or if you have any other solution, please do tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg, I've realized jobs cannot be used for SWT application. As an alternative, I've used

> Thread.start() => Creates a background thread
>
> Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {}) => A background thread
>   cannot update UI,so this is used

Ref:-
[Run thread in background in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188659/run-thread-in-background-in-java)
[How to update JFrame Label within a Thread? - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250406/how-to-update-jframe-label-within-a-thread-java)
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t43753.html

I hope this would help someone who are looking for multithreading solutions in SWT.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse job classes are in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs`. The main class to submit a job is `Job`.

Usually used by doing:

```java
Job job = new MyJob();
job.schedule();
```

where `MyJob` is a class which extends `Job`. You implement the `run` method to do your work.

See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2Fpackage-summary.html for a description of the various classes

Also see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2Fclass-use%2FJob.html for a longer overview

Comment: Hey Greg, I couldn't find     org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs in my version of eclipse.

Comment: Make sure your bundle MANIFEST.MF either depends on org.eclipse.core.jobs or package-imports org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.

Comment: Hey nitind, I didn't get your statement. Can you describe it in little more detail.

Comment: You can only use this sort of thing in an Eclipse plugin. They are not available in a simple Java app.

Comment: Ohhh...so is there any simple way that lets me manage multhreading in SWT.